# How to ignore empty fields in Ionic / Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function for the user to be able to change his own details in his account like his description or social links etc...

However, when I submit the form, it replaces everything and the empty values just erase the field in the database.

Any way to submit the form and replace **ONLY** the values that have been entered in the field and ignore the empty ones ?

Here is my controller :

```
var database = firebase.database();
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
  var descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#description');
  var cityInput = document.querySelector('#city');
  var ageInput = document.querySelector('#age');
  var hobbiesInput = document.querySelector('#hobbies');
  var facebookInput = document.querySelector('#facebook');
  var twitterInput = document.querySelector('#twitter');
  var instagramInput = document.querySelector('#instagram');
  var youtubeInput = document.querySelector('#youtube');
  var snapchatInput = document.querySelector('#snapchat');
  var linkedinInput = document.querySelector('#linkedin');
  var emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');
  var passwordInput = document.querySelector('#password');
  var saveButton = document.querySelector('#save');



  saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var name = nameInput.value;
      var description = descriptionInput.value;
      var city = cityInput.value;
      var age = ageInput.value;
      var hobbies = hobbiesInput.value;
      var facebook = facebookInput.value;
      var twitter = twitterInput.value;
      var instagram = instagramInput.value;
      var youtube = youtubeInput.value;
      var snapchat = snapchatInput.value;
      var linkedin = linkedinInput.value;
      var email = emailInput.value;
      var password = passwordInput.value;


      firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).set({
          name: name,
          description: description,
          city: city,
          age: age,
          hobbies: hobbies,
          facebook: facebook,
          twitter: twitter,
          instagram: instagram,
          youtube: youtube,
          snapchat: snapchat,
          linkedin: linkedin,
          email: email,
          password: password,

      });

      receiveNewData();
    function receiveNewData() {
        // check if there's new data added
        firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).on('child_added', function(msg) {
            var data = msg.val();
            // your new data
            console.log(data);
            $state.go("tab.account");
        });
    }

  });
```

Comment: What if you load the user data and fill the fields with the old values on page load? This way if the user doesn't edit anything, the old values will be saved again, so nothing changes.

Comment: That is exactly what I did ! I am answering my own question in a few :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people, like me, that are new to this, here is the solution I found : Autocomplete the fields that have a value already so when I submit the form it is saved again with the same value.

The code :

```
var database = firebase.database();
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
  var descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#description');
  var cityInput = document.querySelector('#city');
  var ageInput = document.querySelector('#age');
  var hobbiesInput = document.querySelector('#hobbies');
  var facebookInput = document.querySelector('#facebook');
  var twitterInput = document.querySelector('#twitter');
  var instagramInput = document.querySelector('#instagram');
  var youtubeInput = document.querySelector('#youtube');
  var snapchatInput = document.querySelector('#snapchat');
  var linkedinInput = document.querySelector('#linkedin');
  var emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');
  var passwordInput = document.querySelector('#password');
  var saveButton = document.querySelector('#save');
  var database = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + userId);

 // Retrieve information into the fields already filled in Database
  database.on('value', function(snapshot) {
     var displayName = snapshot.val().name;
      var description = snapshot.val().description;
      var displayCity = snapshot.val().city;
      var displayAge = snapshot.val().age;
      var displayHobbies = snapshot.val().hobbies;
      var displayFacebook = snapshot.val().facebook;
      var displayTwitter = snapshot.val().twitter;
      var displayInstagram = snapshot.val().instagram;
      var displayYoutube = snapshot.val().youtube;
      var displaySnapchat = snapshot.val().snapchat;
      var displayLinkedin = snapshot.val().linkedin;
      var displayEmail = snapshot.val().email;
      var displayPassword = snapshot.val().password;
       $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.displayName = displayName;
            $scope.description = description;
            $scope.displayCity = displayCity;
            $scope.displayAge = displayAge;
            $scope.displayHobbies = displayHobbies;
            $scope.displayFacebook = displayFacebook;
            $scope.displayTwitter = displayTwitter;
            $scope.displayInstagram = displayInstagram;
            $scope.displayYoutube = displayYoutube;
            $scope.displaySnapchat = displaySnapchat;
            $scope.displayLinkedin = displayLinkedin;
            $scope.displayEmail = displayEmail;
            $scope.displayPassword = displayPassword;
        });
        document.getElementById("name").value = displayName;
        document.getElementById("description").value = description;
        document.getElementById("city").value = displayCity;
        document.getElementById("age").value = displayAge;
        document.getElementById("hobbies").value = displayHobbies;
        document.getElementById("facebook").value = displayFacebook;
        document.getElementById("twitter").value = displayTwitter;
        document.getElementById("instagram").value = displayInstagram;
        document.getElementById("youtube").value = displayYoutube;
        document.getElementById("snapchat").value = displaySnapchat;
        document.getElementById("linkedin").value = displayLinkedin;
        document.getElementById("email").value = displayEmail;
        document.getElementById("password").value = displayPassword;

  });;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firebase_data = {};
var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

var input_data = {
  nameInput: document.querySelector('#name'),
  descriptionInput: document.querySelector('#description'),
  cityInput: document.querySelector('#city'),
  ageInput: document.querySelector('#age'),
  hobbiesInput: document.querySelector('#hobbies'),
  facebookInput: document.querySelector('#facebook'),
  twitterInput: document.querySelector('#twitter'),
  instagramInput: document.querySelector('#instagram'),
  youtubeInput: document.querySelector('#youtube'),
  snapchatInput: document.querySelector('#snapchat'),
  linkedinInput: document.querySelector('#linkedin'),
  emailInput: document.querySelector('#email'),
  passwordInput: document.querySelector('#password'),
  saveButton: document.querySelector('#save')
}

for(var key in input_data) {
    if(input_data.hasOwnProperty(key) && input_data[key].value.length) {
        firebase_data[key] = input_data[key].value
    }
}

firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).set(firebase_data)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, when doing this, if I leave the field "name" empty and there is already some data in it, here is the error it returns : `Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'accounts.lqxPFkBMpka6NnWkNEtrW1leHk32.name'` any idea ?

Comment: Might just need to send keys if there is data so try something like this